# flink checkpointing halts while async i/o operator is awaiting response

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Async i/o operator (1.15.2) is waiting for the future to return (basically let the embedded function complete its processing), till then checkpointing gets halt at this operator. And only proceeds once it gets finished. attaching the screenshot.

[Checkpointing in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COwH4.png)

Basically I would like to test the scenario where async io is waiting for the response & job is restarted. So ideally the last checkpoint will get restored & technically the async i/o processing should get restarted again with the same set of data.

But as checkpoint is stuck, & if i restart the job, than previous checkpoint is restored which doesn’t have the correct set of data.
Please guide how should I tackle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should never let Flink end up waiting; all i/o should be done asynchronously. Otherwise, as you've seen, you'll end up interfering with checkpointing.

The async i/o operator is designed to help with this, but you must either use an asynchronous client library for connecting to the external service, or make your synchronous calls in another thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64225825/2000823 for an example of how to do this.

Comment: thanks @David, the example really helped to understand the flow & working.